# Loop through database records

Tags: php

Im trying to loop through all my users.

First i fetch the users:

```
include 'database.php';
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE role = :role');
$user = "user";
$records->bindParam(':role', $user); 
$records->execute();
$results = $records -> fetchAll();
```

I get all the users like this:

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
echo $row[0]."</br>";
}
```

The result is:

```
Madses
hans
henk
Piet
Peter
Frek
desley
```

Underneath i have another code which looks like this:

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
echo $row[0]."</br>";
}

$array = $row;

function getFirstValues(&$array, $amount){
    for($i=0; $i<$amount; $i++){
        echo $array[0];
        $shift = array_shift($array);
        array_push($array, $shift);
    }
    echo "<br />";
}

getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);
getFirstValues($array, 4);
```

But this echoes:

```
desley desley desley desley 
desley desley desley desley 
desley desley desley desley 
desley desley desley desley 
desley desley desley desley
```

This is not how it should be. It should start with the first name then the second and so on. Any ideas why this is not working how i want it?

The desired output should be this:

```
madses hans henk piet
peter frek desley madses 
hans henk piet peter 
frek desley madses hans 
henk piet peter frek
```

Comment: can you please add the desired output? it's not clear.

Comment: @inarilo updated how i would like the format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `$array = $row;`, you have set `$array` to the last row from your set of results, so later when you use it in `getFirstValues($array, 4);`, you're just working with that one row. So first of all, don't do that. :) You can just use `getFirstValues($results, 4);` instead.

The problem you'll have after that is that in your `getFirstValues` function, `$array[0]` will be an array (a row) rather than a string. If you change it to `$array[0][0]` it will get the string from the row and then you should get the output you're expecting.

---

Some extra advice - totally optional as you already have something that works.

Using `$results = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` to get an array of strings rather than an array of arrays could simplify things, since you're only selecting a single column anyway.

Also you can avoid a lot of `array_shift` / `array_push` function calls by using a little math to achieve the circular array access you're doing.

```
$rows = 5;
$cols = 4;

$area = $rows * $cols;
$size = count($results);

for ($i=0; $i < $area; $i++) {
    echo $results[$i % $size] . ' ';
    if (($i + 1) % $cols == 0) echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So much verbose to a simple thing, try that:

```
    include 'database.php';
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE role = :role');
    $user = "user";
    $records->bindParam(':role', $user); 
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records -> fetchAll();
    I get all the users like this:

function getFirstValues(&$array, $amount){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($array as $row ) { 
        if ($i != 0 && $i % ($amount-1) == 0) echo $row[0],'</br>';
        else echo $row[0];
        $array[$i] = (isset($array[$i+1])) ? $array[$i+1] : $array[0];
        $i++;
    }
    echo $names;
}

getFirstValues($results, 4);
getFirstValues($results, 4);
getFirstValues($results, 4);
getFirstValues($results, 4);
```

You need to enjoy your excellent idea of referencing the result array!

Comment: It has to be the format i posted, but only with all the users instead of only 1 user.

Comment: why not just use `echo $row[0].'<br/>';`?

Comment: I hate too many echo calls and think it's more scalable to some purposes. Just a dev personal thinking.

Comment: @Kevin.a Why only that format? It's too much processing to a simple task as you show the output

Comment: Thanks, now I understand!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    echo $row[0]."</br>";
}

$array = $row;
```

with

```
$array = array();
foreach( $results as $row ) {
    $array[] = $row[0];
}
```

You are getting only the last name in your data set because currently you are assigning `$row` to `$array`, and after the `for` loop, `$row` contains the last row.